# android Edit Text keyboard appears and suddenly disappears in expandable list

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this strange problem, when I click on edit text, that is in expandable list view. My phone shows keyboard for only one sec.(This does not happen in landscape mode)

**My listRow details xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 

        >
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
    <Button 
       android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Add to list"

        />
    <EditText 
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:hint="Quantity"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListRowGroup xml**

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```